# I need to test json requests on a server. How to create a test server?

Tags: android, json, testing, server

I need to test an android application that sends a json request and receives a corresponding response. How can I create a test server to handle requests and send response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use wamp to create a server which will handle the request and send response.

1. download install wamp server
2. create a test.php file

something like below

```
<?php

$json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
$data = json_decode($json);

$name = $data->name;

$ret=array('name' => $name);

echo $ret;
?>
```

3. put this file into the www folder
4. start wamp server
5. connect the app to this test.php

This basically echoes the json message (name) you send from the android app to the server.

Answer (score 0):

download xampp server from the following link [Apache Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

inside /htdocs folder create {test.php} or {serverfile}
thats it...

Comment: @sharahan has the php ..which handle json as request parameter... and jack u can't expect here for every step... atleast try or show your work

Comment: Oo snap!. Actually I have no idea of PHP, so I ignored that part.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the rest server open source [project on git](https://github.com/jacwright/RestServer).
You can set it up over your local machine wamp(windows) or xampp(linx).